# Map the custom triangle to Camera’s View Angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have make a triangle through my code. see below:

```
void TriangleMaker()
    {
        MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mf.mesh = mesh;

        //vertices
        const int verticeCount = 3;//how many vertices for triangle its 3
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[verticeCount]{
            //bottom left.orgin of the gameobject, 
            new Vector3(0,0,0),
            new Vector3(width,0,0),
            new Vector3(width, height,0)
        };

        //triangles
        int[] tri = new int[6];
        tri[0] = 0; //go clock wise always to make triangle from your vertices
        tri[1] = 1;
        tri[2] = 2;

        //normals
        //show the direction of objects
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[3];
        normals[0] = -Vector3.up;
        normals[1] = -Vector3.up;
        normals[2] = -Vector3.up;

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = tri;
        mesh.normals = normals;
    }
```

The script is attached to child game-object of my camera and its showing the triangle but i want to map exactly my triangle to Camera’s view angle.

[image]

Also tried [GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHGtU.png) as Niki answer suggested and the result is not according to expectation:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHGtU.png): [image]https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html

Comment: I guess you mean you need to map it to Camera's frustum (let's assume it's a pyramid for now). In this case you need to add more details. There are a lot of ways you can map a triangle to a pyramid. Most probably you want to map it on the pyramid's x or y projection. right?

Comment: thanks @NikaKasradze let me add an image to more clearly define. you r almost right

Comment: @NikaKasradze there are 4 trainagle/pyramid require which i want to map on camera view angle so that i can see how much area is cover by the camera. (See image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just found it in Unity docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html

P.S: I was so surprised to find this in docs. I think you are the only person in the world who needs this, finally. :D

**EDIT:**

Ok I edited your script. This visualizes camera's upper frustum plane. Note that this works in global space so move the camera at (0 0 0) position and (0 0 0) rotation to see the result. But I guess you can add the rest of the planes and turn this into local space yourself.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FrustumScript : MonoBehaviour {

private void Start()
{
    TriangleMaker();
}

void TriangleMaker()
{
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh = mesh;

    Camera cam = Camera.main;

    //vertices
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[3]
    {
        new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, cam.farClipPlane)),
        cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, cam.farClipPlane))
    };

    //triangles
    int[] tri = new int[6];
    tri[0] = 0; //go clock wise always to make triangle from your vertices
    tri[1] = 1;
    tri[2] = 2;

    //normals
    //show the direction of objects
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[3];
    normals[0] = -Vector3.up;
    normals[1] = -Vector3.up;
    normals[2] = -Vector3.up;

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = tri;
    mesh.normals = normals;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for valueable input but results are not according to expectation. see updated question

Comment: why did you assing in z ? cam.farClipPlane

Comment: because that's how `ViewportToWorldPoint` works:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html

Comment: i am unable to identify that why the rotation is not correct of the triangle

Comment: as I said, this script works when camera is at (0, 0, 0) with rotation (0, 0, 0). If camera is not in that position/rotation you can move the transform to align it with camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130505/discussion-between-mohammad-faizan-khan-and-nika-kasradze).